# Center an unordered list of boxes

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list of boxes. I want the all to be attracted towards the center of a window
instead of the left side of the window which they currently are.

Is there a function I can use to do this? I have attached my css and html below for reference.

```css
#UL_1 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
  display: inline-block;
  height: 216px;
  text-align: center;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  width: 790px;
  column-rule-color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
  perspective-origin: 395px 108px;
  transform-origin: 395px 108px;
  border: 0px none rgb(225, 225, 225);
  font: normal normal normal normal 15px / 24.75px verbregular;
  margin: 0px;
  outline: rgb(102, 102, 102) none 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
/*#UL_1*/

#LI_2 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(25, 25, 25);
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 39px;
  text-align: center;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  width: 156.656px;
  column-rule-color: rgb(25, 25, 55);
  perspective-origin: 78.3281px 19.5px;
  transform-origin: 78.3281px 19.5px;
  background: rgb(96, 106, 113) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
  border-top: 0px none rgb(25, 25, 25);
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(04, 04, 24);
  border-bottom: 0px none rgb(25, 25, 25);
  border-left: 0px none rgb(22, 25, 25);
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  font: normal normal normal normal 15px / 24.75px verbregular;
  margin: 2.5px 2.5px;
  outline: rgb(55, 55, 55) none 0px;
  padding: 7.5px 22.5px;
}
/*#LI_2*/

#LI_23 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(25, 55, 55);
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 39px;
  text-align: center;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  width: 80.5156px;
  column-rule-color: rgb(25, 55, 55);
  perspective-origin: 40.25px 19.5px;
  transform-origin: 40.25px 19.5px;
  background: rgb(58, 140, 174) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
  border-top: 0px none rgb(25, 25, 25);
  border-right: 0px none rgb(25, 55, 55);
  border-bottom: 0px none rgb(25, 25, 25);
  border-left: 0px none rgb(25, 25, 25);
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  font: normal normal normal normal 15px / 24.75px verbregular;
  margin: 2.5px 2.5px;
  outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
  padding: 7.5px 22.5px;
}
/*#LI_23*/
```

```html
<ul id="UL_1">
  <ul class="center">
    <li id="LI_2">
      a
    </li>
    <li id="LI_3">
      b
    </li>
    <li id="LI_4">
      c
    </li>
    <li id="LI_5">
      d
    </li>
    <li id="LI_6">
      e
    </li>
    <li id="LI_7">
      f
    </li>
    <li id="LI_8">
      . . . .
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: May I know the what you are looking for exact ? I mean share the rough sketch with us and your given css is too messy. :)

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/39gC4Ky.png

Something like this

Comment: Thanks for sharing :)

Comment: I have posted my answer check it once. :)

Comment: You have a class called center in your HTML, but I see no CSS applied to that class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want li inline and centered in page. If i think correctly is very simple:

```css
li {
  width: 50px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
ul {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a your required output please check the demo.

```css
ul {
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  width: 120px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ff7f27;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I added display: inline-block to each li but no change

Comment: Try to recreate the demo as I showed in my demo and your existing CSS code is too messy I think it conflict with other classes or can you share your code in JS fiddle ...so that I can see it closer and I can know the issue and we can know what's going wrong in your code. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.center
{
    text-align: center;
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Add this style....

Answer (score 0):

what class `<ul class = "center">` for?

anyway,

Put your `<ul>....</ul>` between `<div style="text-align:center">` and `</div>`

change `#UL_1` to `.UL_1` since it is a class not id.

remove or unset the width in your `UL_1` css

Done!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.center{text-align:center;}
.center li{display:inline-block}
```